# Specification of jsPlumb.on () function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsplumb

I use jsPlumb library. I don't fully understand a list of arguments of jsPlumb.on() function. I can't find specification of that method in [jsPlumb documentation](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/apidocs/index.html). There is following example of using it:

```
jsPlumb.on("#main", "click", "[savelayout]", function () {});
```

Where `#main` is id of div element, which contains jsPlumb's layout for painting graph, `click` is event, `savelayout` is attribute of button. Meaning of event and attribute is obvious, but I don't understand what value should and can take first argument (`#main` in example).

Is that function some extension of jQuery.on() function? If it true, can anybody explain that mechanism?

**EDIT**

Example of using jsPlumb.on() can be found [here](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/demos/toolkit/spring/index.html) .

Comment: where did you find the example with `jsPlumb.on` ?

Comment: @coding_idiot, I updated question and gave a link to example

Comment: I suggest filing a bug with jsPlumb - https://github.com/sporritt/jsplumb/issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little digging and research, all I can say is that it is one of the internal methods which they chose not to expose.

It is one of those methods which you'd like to keep to make the task easier but won't like to expose, since it's more of an internal method.

I'd suggest filing an issue with jsPlumb to know the exact cause - https://github.com/sporritt/jsplumb/issues

Comment: thank you.
I created issue on [github](https://github.com/sporritt/jsPlumb/issues/425)